# How to simulate a progress bar in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

How can I simulate a progress bar to make my app look a lot more complicated than it is...

```
for _ in 1...4{
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
        print("test")
        self.Proggress.progress += 0.25
    }
}
```

This code is just loading a finished bar without simulating "progress."

Comment: You can add a random value to your progress:
self.Proggress.pregress += Double.random(in: 0..<0.5)

Comment: post code as text not image

Comment: @Sh_Khan thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let progressView = UIProgressView(progressViewStyle: .default)
for _ in 1...4{
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double(i) * 0.5) { 
        self.progressView.setProgress(0.25, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: @Sh_Khan to answer your deleted question, it's obvious that this code snippet will update and **animate** the progress view, not just update

Answer (score 1):

Because all fire at the same time with a duration of `0.5` , do  this by replacing  `_` in the `for` loop with `i`

```
.now() + Double(i) * 0.5
```